# MySQL update if exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been trying to do insert / update records in a mysql table. Cannot use ON DUPLICATE KEY because i have nothing to do with the primary key.

Basically i have to update a record in the database

```
INSERT INTO table (city, state, gender, value) VALUES ("delhi","delhi","M",22)
```

If a record of that city, state, gender exists, then simply overwrite the value.

Can i achieve this without sending two queries from the programming language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

actually you can still use `ON DUPLICATE KEY`, just add a unique index on the following columns, eg

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name ADD UNIQUE index_name (city, state, gender)
```

your query now will be,

```
INSERT INTO table (city, state, gender, value) 
VALUES ('delhi','delhi','M', 22)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = 22
```

Comment: Will this make sure that all combinations of city,state,gender are always unique ?

Comment: @AdityaSingh But only if your three columns are set to `NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that constructs such as `ON DUPLICATE KEY` and `REPLACE INTO` were specifically designed to prevent exactly that. The only other way to prevent two queries from your application layer is by declaring a database function that does the same things.

Therefore, add either a `UNIQUE(city, state, gender)` key or a primary key that spans the same columns. The difference between the two lies in the value range of each column; primary keys force `NOT NULL` whereas `UNIQUE` allows for columns to be `NULL`.

The difference is subtle but can sometimes lead to unexpected results, because **`NULL` values are considered to be unique**. For example, let's say you have this data in your database:

```
nr  | name
123 | NULL
```

If you try to insert another `(123, NULL)` it will not complain when you use `UNIQUE(nr,name)`; this may seem like a [bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8173), but it's not.